# how to Receive JSON data sent by ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the data that want sent to backend, its look like

```
function lihat(){
    let id = "12345678";
    let profile = [{name:"dave", department : "Engginering"},
                   {name:"Tedd", department : "Engginering"}]
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'pages/dashboard/dashboard_be.php'
        data:{
            cekload  : true,
            keys     : id,
            dataList : profile 
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
   })
```

the question, how can I receive all of datas sent by ajax in php script
this what I've tried

```
    $id      = $_POST['keys'];
    $cekload = $_POST['cekload'];
    $data    = json_decode($_POST['dataList'];);

   //I wanna parsing the dataList object and then loop it, how to make it ?
```

thanks, before

Comment: i dont have idea, what is should be?

Comment: `$_POST['dataList']` isn't JSON, it's an array.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST["dataList"]);` will show you the data structure. It will typically be accessed via `foreach ($_POST["dataList"] as $employee) echo $employee["name"];`, etc

Comment: If you really want JSON, use `dataList: JSON.stringify(profile)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to send/receive javascript objects, you need to convert the object to a string before sending and decode it back in php (into an array maybe) before reading.

```
<script>
    let id = "12345678";
    let profile = [{name:"dave", department : "Engginering"},
                   {name:"Tedd", department : "Engginering"}]
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'pages/dashboard/dashboard_be.php',
        data:{
            cekload  : true,
            keys     : id,
            dataList : JSON.stringify(profile) 
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
   });
</script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
$id = $_POST['keys'];
$cekload = $_POST['cekload'];
$data = json_decode($_POST['dataList'], true);

echo $id;
echo $cekload;
print_r($data);
?>
```